# passing html variable to multiple php files

Tags: php, xhtml

I am building a family tree for a class assignment and I have to pass variables from an HTML form to a PHP file for that family member depending on whose information is being updated. I need the form variables to be able to pass to the php file for father, mother, wife, ect.

**HTML File**

```
<form action="handle_family.php" method="post">
<p>Family Member: <select name="name">
<option value="david">David</option>
<option value="linda">Linda</option>
<option value="cayla">Cayla</option>
<option value="sophie">Sophie</option>
<option value="sawyer">Sawyer</option>
</select></p>
<p>Relationship: <select name="relationship">
<option value="father">Father</option>
<option value="mother">Mother</option>
<option value="wife">Wife</option>
<option value="son">Son</option>
<option value="daughter">Daughter</option>
</select></p>
<p>Interests: <input type="text" name="interests" size="60" /></p>
<p>History: <input type="text" name="history" size="60" /></p>
<p>Occupation: <input type="text" name="occupation" size="60" /></p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Page" />
</form>
</div>
```

**handle_family.php**

```
<?php // Script 6.2 - handle_reg.php
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$okay= TRUE;
$relationship= $_POST['relationship'];
$interests= $_POST['interests'];
$history= $_POST['history'];
$occupation= $_POST['occupation'];
$name= $_POST['name'];

if($name == 'david')
{
session_start();
$_SESSION[$father_relationship] = $relationship;
$_SESSION[$father_interests] = $interests;
$_SESSION[$father_occupation] = $occupation;
$_SESSION[$father_name] = $name;
$_SESSION[$father_history] = $history;
include 'david.php';
exit();
}
```

**david.php**

```
<?php // david.php

// Define Variables
$father_name = $_SESSION[$father_name];
$father_relationship = $_SESSION[$father_relationship];
$father_interests = $_SESSION[$father_interests];
$father_history = $_SESSION[$father_history];
$father_occupation = $_SESSION[$father_occupation];



//print father's information
print"<h3>Relationship to Chris</h3>
      <p>$father_relationship</p>
      <h3>History</h3>
      <p>$father_history</p>
      <h3>Occupation</h3>
      <p>$father_occupation</p>
      <h3>Interests</h3>
      <p>$father_interests</p>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary that the Session be Set/Active in all the Files that need access to the Data that were set using `$_Session` and setting the session should be the very first thing on any script that needs to access data stored in the Session Global Variable....

**HTML FILE:**

```
<div>
    <form action="handle_family.php" method="post">
        <p>Family Member: <select name="name">
                <option value="david">David</option>
                <option value="linda">Linda</option>
                <option value="cayla">Cayla</option>
                <option value="sophie">Sophie</option>
                <option value="sawyer">Sawyer</option>
            </select></p>
        <p>Relationship: <select name="relationship">
                <option value="father">Father</option>
                <option value="mother">Mother</option>
                <option value="wife">Wife</option>
                <option value="son">Son</option>
                <option value="daughter">Daughter</option>
            </select></p>
        <p>Interests: <input type="text" name="interests" size="60" /></p>
        <p>History: <input type="text" name="history" size="60" /></p>
        <p>Occupation: <input type="text" name="occupation" size="60" /></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Page" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**handle_family.php FILE:**

```
<?php    // NOTICE THAT THERE IS NOT WHITE-SPACE BEFORE <?php

    // Script 6.2 - handle_reg.php
    // FILE-NAME: handle_reg.php WHERE YOU HAVE TO SET THE SESSION VARIABLE
    //FIRST CHECK IF SESSION EXIST BEFORE STARTING IT:
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['familyTree'])){
        $_SESSION['familyTree'] = array();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        $okay         = TRUE;
        $relationship = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['relationship']));
        $interests    = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['interests']));
        $history      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['history']));
        $occupation   = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['occupation']));
        $name         = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));

        // STORE EACH NAME IN THE SESSION USING THE LOWER-CASED FATHERS-NAME AS A UNIQUE KEY
        $lcName                                                = strtolower($name);
        $_SESSION['familyTree'][$lcName]['father_name']          = $name;
        $_SESSION['familyTree'][$lcName]['father_history']       = $history;
        $_SESSION['familyTree'][$lcName]['father_interests']     = $interests;
        $_SESSION['familyTree'][$lcName]['father_occupation']    = $occupation;
        $_SESSION['familyTree'][$lcName]['father_relationship']  = $relationship;


        if ($lcName == 'david') {
            include 'david.php';
            exit();
        }
    }
```

**david.php FILE:**

```
<?php    // NOTICE THAT THERE IS NOT WHITE-SPACE BEFORE <?php

        // FILE-NAME: david.php 
        //FIRST CHECK IF SESSION EXIST BEFORE STARTING IT:
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
            session_start();
        }


        $name                   = "david";  // MAKE SURE THIS IS LOWER-CASE...
        $fatherInfo             = "";

        if(!isset($_SESSION['familyTree'][$name])) {
            // Define Variables
            $father_name            = $_SESSION['familyTree'][$name]['father_name'];
            $father_history         = $_SESSION['familyTree'][$name]['father_history'];
            $father_interests       = $_SESSION['familyTree'][$name]['father_interests'];
            $father_occupation      = $_SESSION['familyTree'][$name]['father_occupation'];
            $father_relationship    = $_SESSION['familyTree'][$name]['father_relationship'];


            //print father's information
            $fatherInfo = "<h3>Relationship to Chris</h3>"  . PHP_EOL;
            $fatherInfo.= "<p>$father_relationship</p>"     . PHP_EOL;

            $fatherInfo.= " <h3>History</h3>"               . PHP_EOL;
            $fatherInfo.= "<p>$father_history</p>"          . PHP_EOL;

            $fatherInfo.= " <h3>Occupation</h3>"            . PHP_EOL;
            $fatherInfo.= "<p>$father_occupation</p>"       . PHP_EOL;

            $fatherInfo.= " <h3>Interests</h3>"             . PHP_EOL;
            $fatherInfo.= "<p>$father_interests</p>"        . PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo $fatherInfo;
```